# Who wins? Painter's Servant or Mycosynth Lattice?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Painter's Servant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=146022) makes all cards the color of your choice. [Mycosynth Lattice](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=50527) makes all cards colorless. What happens if they're both in play at the same time? Does the most recently played one take precedent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most recently played one takes precidence:

From the rulings on [painter's servent](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=146022):

> 5/1/2008  While Painter's Servant is on the
>   battlefield, an effect that changes an object's colors will overwrite
>   Painter's Servant's effect. For example, casting Cerulean Wisps on a
>   creature will turn it blue, regardless of the color chosen for
>   Painter's Servant.
>
> 5/1/2008   If something affected by
>   Painter's Servant is normally colorless, it will simply be the new
>   color. It won't be both the new color and colorless.

In general continuous effects are applied in time stamp order (rule 613. Interaction of Continuous Effects). More info here: http://wizards.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1030